# Connection String for dynamic OLE DB Destination in SSDT/SSIS for SQLServer2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to SQL Server, but not SQL or programming in general. I have been reading the online documentation and tutorials available to set up a For each loop within SSDT/SSIS that loops through a series of flat files in a folder and creates a DB object for each with the same name.

The loop works, except setting up the Connection String for OLE DB Destination Manager. My Server is called 'OLEGS_LAPTOP' with a database called 'Football Data' and I am using the following Connection String:

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI11.0;Server=OLEGS_LAPTOP;Source=(local);Initial Catalog="+ @[User::FileFound] + "Football Data"+";Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
```

Here, `@[User::FileFound]` represents the variable set up in the Flat File Connection Manager for looping through the files in my chosen local folder. When I try using this Connection String for the OLE DB object, I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [10]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid object name 'dbo.OLE DB Destination'.".

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [10]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for "[dbo].[OLE DB Destination]". Check that the object exists in the database.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to change in my string to get the desired result?

Thanks

**Further to answers/support given so far:**

The error message I am now receiving is:

```
TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [10]]: A destination table name has not been provided.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somehow the string "OLE DB Destination" got into `table\view` mapping (first screenshot) and `[dbo].[OLE DB Destination]` came out as a table name. Perhaps you've replaced table name with this string in the `OpenRowset` property of the `OLE DB Destination` properties window (second screenshot).

[image]

[image]

---

**LATER EDIT**

In order to be able to get table name from variable (assume that you have such variable with table name assigned to it) you need to change your `OLE DB Destination`'s `AccessMode` property to `OpenRowset From Variable` and specify variable name in the `OpenRowsetVariable` property (see image below)

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. what should i put as my table name in the DB Destination Editor then? I've tried using  '@[User::FileFound]', but the editor won't accept that...

Comment: I highly suggest you to try to get your solution working without any dynamic variable mapping for the first time. Connection string does not hold table name at all. It holds only server name and database name.

Comment: check changes in the post

Comment: i got it working with the flat file input functioning in the loop, but with a static name listed in the OLE DB object. this appended every flat file to that one DB table name, which then became massive

Comment: i've amended the DB connection properties as per your guidelines above and now have an error saying a table name has not been provided.

Comment: now try to create some string variable, place there the name of your table, change your destination's `accessmode` to `OpenRowset from Variable` and put your variable name into the `OpenRowsetVariable` property.

Comment: and you do not need to change any DB connection properties. Instead you need to change your OLE DB Destination's properties

Comment: sorry, yes this is what i meant. i have changed ole db destination properties and got this new error

Comment: also, is this a valid connection string still? "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Server=OLEGS_LAPTOP;Source=(local);Initial Catalog="+ @[User::FileFound] + "Football Data"+";Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"

Comment: no, this connection string is wrong. You do not need to change it. Try this insted "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Server=OLEGS_LAPTOP;Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Football Data;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"

Comment: ok, i have amended the connection string and also amended my question to show you the new error message i am now receiving about the missing table name.

Comment: are you sure you've typed table name into the variable you placed into OpenRowsetVariable property? In my case I typed `[dbo].[parent_table]` string into the variable

Comment: im confused as to what you mean by DB source...my process flow has a flat file object plugged straight into db destination object...is this now how it should be?

Comment: `DB destination` of course, it was a typo. check all tings again - it should work now

Comment: im still getting the error when using open rowset from variable that a a table name has not been assigned when trying to create dynamic table names.

Comment: too bad... for you :) you know, it's a very simple scenario for SSIS (i mean to specify table name as variable) and I reproduced (created) this scenario on my side without any problems while we was talking. If you can't figure it out looking to your code\solution by your own eyes, there's nothing I can do for you to help you work it out. if you will be consistent in your actions, moving forward step by step, making things more complex only then the previous step is completed and verified... but, if only it was so, there would be no such question and we would not be talking at all :)